# Taking results from a trained classifier - Image Processing

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

I am working on a gender detection project from images, coded with OpenCV & Python.

I found [this](http://bytefish.de/blog/gender_classification/) blog post and [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_gender_classification.html) opencv tutorial. In these sites they suggest to use fisherfaces method and NearestNeighbor algorithm for making a model for gender classification.

Here is my problem:

I am new in machine learning so after this classification part, I couldn't find how can I apply another image to this classifier and take result form that like this:

```
"This person is Male."
"This person is Female."
```

How can I take result like above from a classifier?

Comment: Once you trained the model, you should provide your input image to the classifier. Then you'll have a prediction of which class your face image belongs.

Comment: @Eliezer Yes, but after I saved my model in .pkl file type how can I apply an image to this model in python?

Comment: Hello, I need same also but I am totally new to machine learning so if you have a script which can do the trick written in python it will be great from you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classifier is teached using reference data. You give him examples for each class (training). Lets say 500 pictures of girls and 500 pictures of guys. You tell the classifier the gender for every picture. Then you give an unknown image to the classifier and he will use the trained "knowledge" to pick one class (if possible).

Read through the OpenCV demo code carefully. Everything you need is in there.

From line 100:

```
Mat testSample = images[images.size() - 1];
int testLabel = labels[labels.size() - 1];
images.pop_back();
labels.pop_back();
// The following lines create an Fisherfaces model for
// face recognition and train it with the images and
// labels read from the given CSV file.
// If you just want to keep 10 Fisherfaces, then call
// the factory method like this:
//
//      cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer(10);
//
// However it is not useful to discard Fisherfaces! Please
// always try to use _all_ available Fisherfaces for
// classification.
//
// If you want to create a FaceRecognizer with a
// confidence threshold (e.g. 123.0) and use _all_
// Fisherfaces, then call it with:
//
//      cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer(0, 123.0);
//
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
model->train(images, labels);
// The following line predicts the label of a given
// test image:
int predictedLabel = model->predict(testSample);
```

Befor they load images and labels using a CSV file. Then just for demo purposes they take the last image from the vector, remove it from the vector and use it as the image under test. (So the image under test won't be among the training data). Then they train the Fisher thing using the remaining images and apply it to the image "testSample"

So all you need to do is replace the testSample with one of your images and print out a senctence depending on the found label.

Comment: @Piglet I saw this opencv demo, but I am not good at c++, I couldn't understand how can I write this "mat" method in python.

Comment: Mat ist the type of the variable testSample. I guess in python you can just leave Mat away.